# Removing doublettes

Tags: mysql, sql

I'm trying to remove doublettes (sometimes triplettes, unfortunately!) from a MySQL table. My issue is that the only unique data available are the primary key, so in order to identify doublettes, you have to take account all the columns.

I've managed to identify all records that have doublettes and copied them along with their doublettes (including their primary keys) to the table `temp`. The source table is called `translation` and it has an integer primary key with the name `TranslationID`. How do I move on from here?  Thanks!

**edit** Available columns are:

```
TranslationID
LanguageID
Translation
Etymology
Type
Source
Comments
WordID
Latest
DateCreated
AuthorID
Gender
Phonetic
NamespaceID
Index
EnforcedOwner
```

The duplicity issue resides with the rows with the `Latest` column assigned `1`.

**edit #2** Thank you, everyone for your time! I've solved the problem by using [WouterH](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1300910/wouterh)'s answer, resulting in the following query:

```
DELETE from translation USING translation, translation as translationTemp
WHERE translation.Latest = 1
AND (NOT translation.TranslationID = translationTemp.TranslationID)
AND (translation.LanguageID = translationTemp.LanguageID)
AND (translation.Translation = translationTemp.Translation)
AND (translation.Etymology = translationTemp.Etymology)
AND (translation.Type = translationTemp.Type)
AND (translation.Source = translationTemp.Source)
AND (translation.Comments = translationTemp.Comments)
AND (translation.WordID = translationTemp.WordID)
AND (translation.Latest = translationTemp.Latest)
AND (translation.AuthorID = translationTemp.AuthorID)
AND (translation.NamespaceID = translationTemp.NamespaceID)
```

Comment: Do you care which record you keep in the original table?

Comment: No, it doesn't matter which record I keep.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can remove duplicates without temporary table or subquery. Delete all rows that have the same data but a different `TranslationID`

```
DELETE from translation USING translation, translation as translationTemp
WHERE (NOT translation.TranslationID = translationTemp.TranslationID)
AND (translation.LanguageID = translationTemp.LanguageID)
AND (translation.Translation = translationTemp.Translation)
AND (translation.Etymology = translationTemp.Etymology)
AND // compare other fields here
```

Answer (score 2):

Create a SELECT statement with your current SELECT as a sub-select, so that you can return a col of IDs that should be removed. Then apply that SELECT in a DELETE FROM statement.

Example (pseudo code):

```
SELECT1 = SELECT ... AS temp; # the table you have right now

SELECT2 = SELECT TranslationID FROM (SELECT1)
```

Final query will look like this:

```
DELETE FROM table_name WHERE TranslationID IN (SELECT2);
```

You just need to insert the SELECT with sub-select in the final query.

Top stop duplicates in future you can change your engine to the InnoDB engine like this:

```
ALTER TABLE table_name ENGINE=InnoDB;
```

Then add a `Unique` constraint to the TranslationID field.

Comment: actually, your query would delete the rows the OP wants to *keep*. you should inverse the logic, using `WHERE .. NOT IN (..)`

Comment: @Kaii `I've managed to identify all doublettes and copied their data (including their primary key) to the table temp.` Doesn't that mean he wants to delete the records that have those IDs from temp table (becuse temp contains all the duplicates)?

Comment: I'm sorry! This is definitely a language barrier for me to conquer. The table `temp`  contains all doublettes and triplettes. I can't merely do a `DELETE ... IN(SELECT TranslationID FROM temp)` as this would delete all records entirely.

Answer (score 0):

If the doublettes/triplettes are identical except for the primary key, then you can select all records from temp which are identical to another except for having a larger primary key than that other; this will give you temp w/ the record w/ the minimum key for each doublet/triplette.  You can then delete these records from translation.

Answer (score 0):

Instead of identifying the lines that aren't unique, I would try to copy the valid data to a new table, and then remove the old one and replace it by this new, cleaned table.

I can see of two ways:

- Using the [`DISTINCT`](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/distinct-optimization.html) keyword in your SQL query ([source](http://www.cyberciti.biz/faq/howto-removing-eliminating-duplicates-from-a-mysql-table/));
- Using a `GROUP BY` statement on all columns ([source](http://www.justin-cook.com/wp/2006/12/12/remove-duplicate-entries-rows-a-mysql-database-table/)).